# Ktable to KGroupTable - Schema Not available (State Store ChangeLog Schema not registered)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka topic - let's activity-daily-aggregate,
and I want to do aggregate (add/sub) using KGroupTable. So I read the topic using the

```
final KTable<String, GenericRecord> inputKTable =
      builder.table("activity-daily-aggregate",Consumed.with(new StringSerde(), getConsumerSerde());

Note: getConsumerSerde - returns >> new GenericAvroSerde(mockSchemaRegistryClient)
```

```
2.Next Step,
```

```
inputKTable.groupBy(
        (key,value)->KeyValue.pair(KeyMapper.generateGroupKey(value), new JsonValueMapper().apply(value)),
        Grouped.with(AppSerdes.String(), AppSerdes.jsonNode())
        );
```

Before Step 1 and 2 I have configured MockSchemaRegistryClient with

```
 mockSchemaRegistryClient.register("activity-daily-aggregate-key",
                    Schema.parse(AppUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("/avro/key.avsc")));
       mockSchemaRegistryClient.register("activity-daily-aggregate-value",
                    Schema.parse(AppUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("/avro/daily-activity-aggregate.avsc")))
```

While I run the topology - using test cases, I get an error at Step 2.

org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000011, topic=activity-daily-aggregate, partition=0, offset=0, stacktrace=org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema: {"type":"record","name":"FactActivity","namespace":"com.ascendlearning.avro","fields":.....}

Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema Not Found; error code: 404001

The Error goes off when i register the schema with mockSchemaRegistryClient,

**stream-app-id**-activity-daily-aggregate-STATE-STORE-0000000010-changelog-key

**stream-app-id**-activity-daily-aggregate-STATE-STORE-0000000010-changelog-value
=> /avro/daily-activity-aggregate.avsc

Do we need to do this step? I thought it might be handled automatically by the topology

Comment: I don't why this is required but to avoid hardcoding, I have named the Processor and State Store in the DSL definition.` final KTable<String, GenericRecord> learnerActivityDailyAggregateKTable =
    builder
    .table("activity-daily-aggregate",          Consumed.with(new StringSerde(),new GenericAvroSerde(analyticsSchemaRegistryClient))
.withName("ACTIVITY_TOPIC_READER"),Materialized.as("ACTIVITY_TOPIC_READER_STATE_STORE"));
`

Comment: So the Schema registry key changes to stream-app-id-ACTIVITY_TOPIC_READER_STATE_STORE-key, and  stream-app-id-ACTIVITY_TOPIC_READER_STATE_STORE-value

Answer (score 0):

From the blog,
https://blog.jdriven.com/2019/12/kafka-streams-topologytestdriver-with-avro/

When you configure the same mock:// URL in both the Properties passed into TopologyTestDriver, as well as for the (de)serializer instances passed into createInputTopic and createOutputTopic, all (de)serializers will use the same MockSchemaRegistryClient, with a single in-memory schema store.

```
 // Configure Serdes to use the same mock schema registry URL
    Map<String, String> config = Map.of(
        AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, MOCK_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL);
    avroUserSerde.configure(config, false);
    avroColorSerde.configure(config, false);

    // Define input and output topics to use in tests
    usersTopic = testDriver.createInputTopic(
        "users-topic",
        stringSerde.serializer(),
        avroUserSerde.serializer());
    colorsTopic = testDriver.createOutputTopic(
        "colors-topic",
        stringSerde.deserializer(),
        avroColorSerde.deserializer());
```

I was not passing the mock registry client - schema URL in the serdes passed to input /output topic.